# Excel macro to add date for any change in data in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to parse an entire row in a particular excel sheet for any change in data in that row. If there is any change in data in that row then i want to add the date in which that particular cell of that row. I want to pass the row as an input. I tried the following code but it doesnt work.

---

```
Private Function User_func1(ByVal i As Long)

    Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To j = 100
        If Cells(i, j).Value > 1 Then
            Cells(i, 2) = Now()
        End If
    Next j

End Function
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: Your table must have 100 column, Does it?

Comment: 1) replace `For j = 1 To j = 100` with `For j = 1 To 100`. 2) Be carefull, because when you change one cell your code is going to change another cell, which will fire the `Worksheet_Change` event again and again...

Comment: Hello, there is no error log. it always shows ZERO in the cell where the macro is used.. I also tried and changed j = 1 To 100. No change in results however

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event in the sheet you want to scan.

```
Option Explicit

Const RowtoTest = 2

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Row = RowtoTest Then
    Target.Value = Date
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Option 2**: Get the row to test from a certain cell, lets say Cell "A1" (value is set to 2, means look for changes in cells in row 2).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
' compare the row number to the number inputted as the row to test in cell A1
If Target.Row = Range("A1").Value Then
    Target.Value = Date
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Shai, Thanks for your answer! I am sorry but i must admit i have just started using excel macros and not good at it. I tried to add this code in the worksheet "view code" but did not work. I prefer if you can give me a simpler approach like the one mentioned in the code above. Reason is sometimes i will have to parse 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 columns. This loop method with passing arguments for rows as arguments in the function could be helpful. I dont know why my code which is simple isnt working. Can you please please help!